# Question about opening a lightbox whenever a link with a certain path/filename

Tags: jquery, lightbox

The site I'm working on has links and buttons that give users the ability to edit a presentation.

The client wants to open a light box with a notification window whenever you're going to an edit page.

I'm pulling in the following page to the main page to try to accomplish this.

The notification would either go back, or continue to the edit the presentation.

The main question I have is how to open a light box whenever there is a link or a button which links to a url containing a certain path/filename. I think I'm close, but can't figure out exactly what I'm missing. Here's what I have so far.

If you know how to answer the continue question as well, then you'd be my new hero :).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    function() {
        if ( document.location.href.indexOf('slidecreate/editor/') >=0) {
                    $('.open').click(function(){
                    $('.notifylightbox, .notifybox').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.notifybox').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.notifylightbox, .notifybox').css('display', 'block');
                });

                $('.notifyback').click(function(){
                    close_box();
                });

                $('.notifylightbox').click(function(){
                    close_box();
                });
                }<!--endif-->
            });<!--endifstartfunction-->


            function close_box()
            {
                $('.notifylightbox, .notifybox').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                    $('.notifylightbox, .notifybox').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }<!--endclosebox-->
 });<!--enddocready-->
```

```
<style>
.notifylightbox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url("../img/dashboard/lightboxbg.png");
    z-index:50;
    display:none;
}

.notifybox {
    background: url("../img/dashboard/noticebg.png") no-repeat;
    margin: -100px auto auto auto;
    width: 495px;
    height: 220px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:51;
}

.notifyback {
    position: relative;
    left: 295px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 125px;
}

.notifycontinue {
    position: relative;
    left: 302px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 125px;
    }


</style>
</head>






<body>
    <div class="notifylightbox"></div>
        <div class="notifybox">
        <p style="width: 300px; position: relative; top: 95px; left: 150px;">Your custom edited presentation will be saved to your user space and will not modify any base templates.</p>
            <img class="notifyback" src="../img/dashboard/noticeback.png" />
            <img class="notifycontinue" src="../img/dashboard/noticecontinue.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('a[*="/piece/of/url/youre/looking/for"]').click(function (e) {

    //...show your lightbox/dialog here...

    //to stop browser from following clicked link, return false:
    return false; 
});
```

Since you're already using JQuery you might want to use [JQuery UI Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) instead of custom confirmation box.